# How to compress output file using FFmpeg - Apple ProRes 422

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to video encoding and trying to encode a music video for the apple itunes video store.

I am currently using FFmpeg for encoding.

My source file is mp4 file type and  file size=650MB

I encode the file using the Apple ProRes 422 (HQ) codec and output a mov file.

```
ffmpeg -y -i busy1.mp4  -vcodec prores -profile:v 3 -r "29.97" -c:a mp2   busy2.mov
```

I am trying to encode the video according to the following specs:

● Apple ProRes 422 (HQ)
● VBR expected at ~220 Mbps

Encoded PASP    Converted to ProRes From
1920 x 1080 1:1 HDCAM SR, D5, ATSC
1280 x 720  1:1 ATSC progressive

29.97 interlaced frames per second for video sourced

Music Video Audio Source Profile

● MPEG-2 layer II stereo
● 384 kpbs
● 48Khz

The file is encoded perfectly fine however the output is 6Gb in size.

Why would the file be so large after encoding?

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

The `Apple ProRes` is not intended for high compression. It is an intermediate codec used in post-production which optimizes the storage as opposed to keeping the videos uncompressed while retaining a high image quality.

You are supposed to use your **uncompressed** source file as input to retain the maximum quality and not an already lossy-compressed video.

You only mentioned the container format of your input file: `MP4` but not the codecs which is the actual important information.

Since the `HQ` flavor of `ProRes` uses `220 Mbps` the file size can actually increase but you **don't** gain anything in quality if the source is lossy.

See more here: [Apple ProRes](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Apple_ProRes)

Answer (score 0):

Though you don't gain much by decompressing a source clip thats "Lossy", you do gain in some ways.  Compressed video uses a compressed color palette, which can be detrimental when making color corrections or corrections to detail level, especially when you're given interlaced footage to clean up.  If you put in the time on detail, microcontrast, and color, you know the benefit of expanded color detail for compressing back down.  It also encodes much faster on the back end of your edits.  Simply compressing the data down is faster than expanding and then compressing.
However, if you recompress all your video down to the same size and codec as what went in, most encoders and editor apps now test the datarate of the GOP, working on only those GOP's that need to be redone to fit the new settings.